# onChildAdded is fired on every app start, but no new entries in the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On every start of my app, I receive the same "onChildAdded" actions. So my app thinks, these child where added recently. But they are in the database from the beginning. 
So when I close my app and start it again, I receive these actions again. Everytime.

I also call

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

in my Application class.

How can I solve this issue, so the listeners are really only called, when new data was added to the database?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to keep the key of the newest item the user has seen in local storage (e.g. `SharedPreferences`). Then when you start the activity again, start at that key:

```
String lastSeenKey = sharedPreferences.getString("lastSeenKey", "-");
ref.orderByKey().
   .startAt(lastSeenKey)
   .addChildEventListener(...
```

And then in `onChildAdded()` make sure that you store the latest key in the shared preferences.

Comment: Sounds good, but why does firebase tells my app, that there is a new entry, when there is no new entry?

Comment: And I don't get any updates for the already added events, right?

Comment: It's just how the API is defined. `ChildAdded` will immediately be called for each existing child and then for any new child added afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `once('child_added')` or `once('value')` method to receive all data entries from firebase when your **app starts**. Then **save them** locally to some variable.
And after that you subscribe for event. When it fires - you firstly check if that child is already known. If not - do actions you need.